# What is the alternative way for Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a single ton which is working fine, but  i don't want to use singleton instead any alternative best way
find my code for reference

Myclass.h

```
+ (instancetype)shareInformation;
```

Myclass.m

```
+ (instancetype)shareInformation
{
    static Myclass *manager;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        manager = [[Myclass alloc] init];       
    }); 
    return manager;
}
```

MyNextClass.m

```
[[Myclass shareInformation] methodofMyclass:^(NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

    //my code
}];
```

i have a class `Myclass` in which i am using a singleton to init `manager = [[Myclass alloc] init]`; and i am calling this in other class `MyNextClass` but i don't want to do this in this way i mean i don't want to use singleton pattern i need some this alternative for what i do here

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want done differently?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it or provide a bit more details?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You should use a singleton pattern if you need access to only one instance of this class throughout your app.

Comment: ya i edited my question

Comment: This question is too broad and would require intimate knowledge of your code architecture to offer a solution on how to convert a singleton class into a useable regularly-instanced class.

Comment: @iphonedevkumar It doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. Maybe pick up a book on design patterns used in objective-c and you'll have a better idea. But no one here know's what you're trying to do, so we can't really advise you on a pattern to use

Comment: chris i want to know the alternative way of singleton.

Comment: If you don't want a singleton, don't use one. Your other option is to create an instance like any other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to avoid using the singleton as it's considered an anti-pattern.
A solution would be to use a dependency injection container to wire up your application and configure it to resolve your object as a single instance.
I'm not familiar with ios development but Typhoon looks like popular choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton or you can use a normal instance, it's up to you. One of the major benefits of a singleton is so that you can get a reference to it anywhere without difficulty.

You could always create a class, and pass a reference of it anywhere you want to use it. For example in your view controller you create it, make sure you create a property of it in your following view controllers and then pass that same reference to the new view controller.

It's best to use a singleton if that's what you're trying to accomplish and you only need one instance though.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, for "global" data, is to make use of the AppDelegate.  You can place simple properties in the AppDelegate itself, or define a property (or explicit "getter" method) which returns a pointer to some more complex "global" object.

Note that using the AppDelegate this way is considered "bad form" by many, but there's really not that much bad about it, other than accessing the AppDelegate itself is a bit awkward.  (And it upsets the sensibilities of those who are sure they know what "separation of concerns" *really* means.)